# SPA with refresh tokens stored in cookie - how to configure with IdentityServer4?

Tags: asp.net-core, oauth, jwt, single-page-application, identityserver4

I have an SPA which communicates with an API using a long-lived self-contained JWT for auth.

The SPA is currently storing this JWT in Local Storage.

Apart from this being pretty bad from a security standpoint, the other major problem with is that I have way of revoking access to the API (which btw, needs to remain stateless). One a user has a token, they can use it indefinitely.

I'd like to start using refresh tokens. I know these are typically not recommended for SPAs, however after reading [The Ultimate Guide to handling JWTs on frontend clients](https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/) I believe there is a way to do this securely.

What I would like:

- When user logs in (password grant) the server responds with a short-life access_token ONLY, but sets a HttpOnly cookie with the refresh token.
- The client stores the access_token in memory, and uses it when making API requests.
- When the access_token is near expiry, I'd make a request to the auth server to refresh the token. Because a cookie was set by the auth server, it would be automatically included in the request. The server responds with an updated access_token which we store in memory.
- If the user navigates away from the SPA and returns later, we can simply make a request to the auth server to refresh the token, which gives us a brand new one (no need to store anything in local storage).

This would seem to be about the most secure option, minimising both XRSF and CSRF:

- If somebody manages to inject some code into the SPA and steals an access_token, it expires after 5 minutes anyway. The injected code never gets access to the refresh_token.
- You can't trick a user into making CSRF API requests because you don't have the access_token (the access token effectively serves as a CSRF token).
- If somebody did somehow manage to get access to the refresh_token, it can be revoked on the auth server.

If this method is as full proof as I think it is (prove me wrong, please!), why is it seldom mentioned online?

The IdentityServer4 docs don't seem to cover this. Can anybody suggest how it might be implemented? I hoped that there might be a property I could set on in the Client config along the lines of `UseCookiesForRefresh`, but no.

Comment: Did you manage to Refresh AccessTokens by using RefreshToken?  May I know how do you protect the client_secret in Spa which is required in Refresh process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ReferenceToken type instead of Jwt Token to revoke the tokens whenever the user's session is ended (or logout).  [Reference Token](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reference_tokens.html?highlight=Reference%20Token)

You need to change the AccessTokenType in Client configuration

```
new Client
    {
        ClientName = "OAuth Test",
        ClientId = "TestClientId",
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Hybrid,
        AccessTokenLifetime = 300,
        AllowOfflineAccess = true,
        AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Reference,
        ......
    }
```

When the user logs out, you can use the following lines to revoke all tokens generated within that session.

```
await _interaction.RevokeTokensForCurrentSessionAsync();
```